# Como acessar elementos de um iframe de uma página externa?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Preciso acessar um id que tem dentro de uma página externa que estou renderizando em um iframe no meu site.

Está ocorrendo aquele erro de permissão. Como resolver isso?

Esse é o link da página:
http://portal.4stations.com.br/embed/d0b84b4a7a/

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fz9f8/

Observerm meu X-Frame-Options. Está com "localhost:3000", isso funciona?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Você só pode acessar elementos da página do iframe se o iframe for do mesmo domínio da página que contém o iframe.

Existem várias formas para solucionar esse problema, uma delas é definir o header x-frame-options. Esse header pode ter os valores NONE e SAMEORIGIN. Definindo o header para SAMEORIGIN, fica possível acessar os elementos.

Uma opção para definir o x-frame-options é assim:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="SAMEORIGIN">
</head>
```

Isso vai funcionar se ambas as páginas estão no mesmo domínio, isto é, estão sendo servidas pelo mesmo servidor com a mesma URL.

Para usar o a opção allow-from, no seu caso:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="ALLOW-FROM http://portal.4stations.com.br/">
</head>
```

Porém, o allow-from não tem suporte no Chrome e no Safari, conforme:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Já existe uma biblioteca para a troca de mensagens entre página e iframe: http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Comment: Tenho acesso ao código do site da página externa e setei la no controller o header x-frame-options, como acesso agora?

Comment: setei la no header como http://localhost:3000, funciona?

Comment: Veja a nova versão da resposta.